# how many infinities are there?

Tags: set-theory

I'm a past-graduate in mathematics and familiar with the basics of ordinals and cardinals.
My question is: how many infinities are there? There are obviously infinitely many, but since we already know that there are different kinds of infinity, the question remains for me: how many infinitely many? Is this a sensible question at all?

Comment: A proper class of them, since we can produce distinct ones for every ordinal.

Comment: Infinitely many :P

Comment: The collection of all cardinals in ZFC forms a proper class and does not form a set. This means roughly speaking that it is larger than any set whose existence ZFC proves. As I recall the usual argument is that if $A$ were the set of all cardinals, then the power set of $A$ would be a cardinal which by Cantor's theorem is not in $A$. It is important that I am talking about ZF(C); in NF(U), the situation is rather different.

Comment: This is essentially asking how many ordinal numbers there are. But there can't be a  number of ordinal numbers, or that number would itself be an ordinal number, larger than any other ordinal number, which is absurd.  This is the [Burali-Forti paradox](http://enwp.org/Burali-Forti_paradox).

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/283581/how-many-different-sizes-of-infinity-are-there

Comment: If the question is not how many different ordinals/cardinals are there, but rather how many different notions of infinity are there, then please let me know, and I'll reopen so the question can be closed as a different duplicate.